# Why does this change of variables fail?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the definite integral:

$$ \int_{-2}^2{ \sqrt{4-x^2}dx }$$

when I perform a change of variables letting:

$$ u = 4-x^2$$

that changes the definite integral to:

$$ \int_{u=0}^{u=0} \sqrt{4-x^2}dx$$

I realize the function isn't in terms of u, but it really shouldn't matter what the function is. I know for a fact that the integral is equal to 2π. But why when I change the variables does this occur?

Comment: The substitution doesn't work since $u=4-x^2$ is not one-to-one on $x\in[-2,2]$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Do you mind explaining way it not being one-to-one affects the change of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should seperate the range `0<=x<=2` and `-2<=x<0` as `du` is expressed differently in terms of `dx` in those 2 ranges